# How to type a function attribute in NamedTuple

Tags: python, mypy

I have a piece of code like

```
from typing import Callable, NamedTuple, TypeVar


def f1(x: int) -> int:
    return x


def f2(y: str) -> int:
    return len(y)


T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


class Config(NamedTuple):
    func: Callable[[T], int]


c1 = Config(func=f1)
c2 = Config(func=f2)
```

Mypy complains:

```
toy.py:19:18: error: Argument "func" to "Config" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "Callable[[Config], int]"
toy.py:20:18: error: Argument "func" to "Config" has incompatible type "Callable[[str], int]"; expected "Callable[[Config], int]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why would it expect `"Callable[[Config], int]"`?

I'm using Python-3.8, and mypy==0.800

Comment: Why are you using `TypeVar` there?

Comment: I may be using `TypeVar` incorrectly. What's the right way to specify a function that accepts either an int or a string?

Comment: `Callable[[int | str], int]` or `Callable[[Union[int, str]], int]` for versions below 3.10

Comment: FWIW, the proper solution would be to make ``Config`` generic over ``T``. However, none of the type checkers I tried currently support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the type of that field to be *either* a function of an `int` or a function of a `str`, you can do

```
class Config(NamedTuple):
    func: Callable[[int], int] | Callable[[str], int]
```

This describes the union of two function types.

However, this is not a useful type. If Python had intersection types, this would be equivalent to

```
Callable[[int & str], int]
```

And `int & str` is, well, the empty type. There are no values which are both `int` and `str` at the same time. So this is a type of functions that can never be called. And `isinstance` won't help you here since you can't typecheck the declared argument types of a `Callable`.

As mentioned in the comments, you can do

```
Callable[[int | str], int]
```

but this is the type of functions that accept *either* an int or a string, not the type of functions that accept only one of the two selectively.

Comment: yeah, union doesn't work, ```toy.py:19:18: error: Argument "func" to "Config" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "Callable[[Union[int, str]], int]"
```. I think the union of two function types may be what I need. Can you explain a bit why TypeVar doesn't work or is not suitable here?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. There is no argument that is compatible with both `f1` and `f2`, so the only type that could possibly be assigned either of those functions is a type that we can do nothing with. You need to think about what you're trying to do with this value and how you use it.

Comment: It is pretty trivial and not exactly uncommon to use such "callable union" types via EAFP. That the type system cannot express that doesn't make the actual usage impossible.